# Why is my react Table not updating the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table, react-table-v7

I got a react Table that I want to delete or modify my data.
My code is below for all my cells.

```
    deleteTableElement = (row) => {
        let data = this.state.list.data;
        data.splice(row.id, 1);
        this.setState({
            list:{
                ...this.state.list,
                data:data
            }
        })
    };

    actionsCell = (columns) => {
        columns.push({
            Header: "Accion",
            Cell: (props) => {
                console.log(props);
                return (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            display: "flex",
                            justifyContent: "space-around",
                        }}
                    >
                        <i
                            onClick={() => this.deleteTableElement(props.row)}
                            className="material-icons"
                            style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                            delete
                        </i>
                    </div>
                );
            },
        });
        return columns;
    };
```

In this case, I want to modify the item. The react table is not updating.

Comment: How di you call ` actionsCell `? and what is data structure of `columns`?

Comment: is setState not enought? i mean i thought that was the way

Comment: Any reason for async in`actionsCell` ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky nop, i got a solution for edit content just with `e.values = {...e.values, id:xvar}`, now i need the solution for deleting a row

Comment: I cannot understand your code. Can you post some data and a markup example of the  table you try to render?

Comment: Don't mutate state - `splice` mutates state. Don't do it. Use `filter` instead.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky im trying to delete a row, just that, im sorry for my code  : /, i pass the data from my state, when i change my state react table didnt change the data

Comment: OK, put `console.log(this.state.list);` before and after splice.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky the item was removed from state, but my table still doesnt change

Comment: Because your render depends on the props, not on the state

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky - no, it's because he mutated state.

Comment: this is how i send the data <DataTable {...this.state.list} />

Comment: @Adam i did your solution, but i doesnt change :/

Comment: @Adam OK, I see

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky - based on the partial code that the OP is showing and described in a comment on my answer, I'm thinking you could be right and the OP doesn't actually need state here at all. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @ReinaldoPastran maybe it's a good idea to describe clearly the whole component and its data and rewrite it in a snippet or fiddle

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky - you're right, this question can't be answered without a reproducible stackblitz, or something of that nature.

Comment: stack doesnt let me edit and paste all of my code : /

the render is like 
`(!this.state.list) ?return "Loading...": <DataTable {...this.state.list} />`

Comment: componentDidMount start with a fetch

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Do you know where I can see an example to eliminate a row?

Comment: @ReinaldoPastran an example of table that deletes a row on click?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky yes https://react-table.tanstack.com/ doesnt have 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever your component unexpectedly doesn't update, it's because you're mutating state. Literally 100% of the time:

```
        let data = this.state.list.data;
        data.splice(row.id, 1); // <- splice mutates an array, mutating state is bad
        this.setState({
            list:{
                ...this.state.list,
                data:data
            }
        })
```

should be:

```
        this.setState({
            list:{
                ...this.state.list,
                data:data.filter((d,i) => i !== row.id)
            }
        })
```

Comment: i did it, this is how i set my data in react Table
 `const [datas, setDatas] = React.useState(data);

    const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
            Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
        }),
        []
    );
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setDatas(data);
    }); `

Comment: @ReinaldoPastran - I have no idea what that code means, all I know is that when I see somebody `splice`-ing (or otherwise mutating) a state variable, I know immediately what is wrong.

Comment: @ReinaldoPastran - although what that code does indicate to me is that you might not be clear on the difference between props and state - it appears possible that your component should not be using state at all and instead should just be rendering based on `props`, but I'd need to see your actual full code in order to determine that.

Comment: How do I make the state depend on the properties

Comment: @ReinaldoPastran - This component doesn't **own** this data - this data is **owned** (has it's source of truth, state) by another component and just passes the data into this one (via props) to render it. So, instead of having state in this component - you should just use the props passed in to render the data. Additionally, the component that passes in the data to this one should also pass in a `handleDelete` function prop, this component will call that when the user pushes a button. The work of deleting the row is done in the component that **owns** the data, which is not this one.

Comment: idk why this didnt works last time, now i see this is the best way thank you mate

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of a table with deletable rows.

Pass your initial rows to the component as a prop and copy them to the state.

On click delete button, make a copy or rows without deleted row and update the state. The table will re-render.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyTable = ({rows, columns}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(rows); // Copy rows to the state
  
  const deleteRow = index => {
    // Create a copy of row data without the current row
    const newData = [...data.slice(0, index), ...data.slice(index + 1)];
    // Update state
    setData(newData);
  }

  return (
    <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {columns.map(column => (<th key={column}>{column}</th>))}
        <th/>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((row, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{row.text}</td>
          <td>{row.value}</td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={() => deleteRow(index)}>Delete Me !</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>  
    </table>
    )
}

const tableRows = [
  {
    text: 'A',
    value: 100,
  },
  {
    text: 'B',
    value: 200,
  },
  {
    text: 'C',
    value: 300,
  },
  {
    text: 'D',
    value: 400,
  },
];

const tableColumns = ['Text', 'Count'];


ReactDOM.render(
  <MyTable rows={tableRows} columns={tableColumns} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: friend I think it's my fault for not explaining well, I'm using the reactTable API, and I need to remove the data from that component 
https://react-table.tanstack.com/

Comment: @Adam it's based on assumption that the initial rows data is immutable, so the state is a subset of the passed prop. There is an alternative: pass an update callback as a prop and call it when a row is deleted. In that case the state will become obsolete

Comment: @ReinaldoPastran I see. You can do it with react-table exactly the same way: bind an event to a button click, remove rows from your data, update the state and then your table will re-render with the new data

Comment: `<i
                            onClick={() => this.deleteTableElement(props.row)}
                            className="material-icons"
                            style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                            delete
                        </i>` 
there is the event with bind or an arrow function
`deleteTableElement = (row) => {
        let data = this.state.list.data;
        data.splice(row.id, 1);
        this.setState({
            list:{
                ...this.state.list,
                data:data
   }
    })
 };`

Comment: OK, now replace `splice` with a code similar to snippet's one and make sure you don't update the state with the same array (event when it's smaller, it has the same ref as before splice). The code with `[...slice, ...slice]` builds a new array and updates the state properly

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky `There is an alternative: pass an update callback as a prop and call it when a row is deleted. In that case the state will become obsolete` <- Not doing this is what's causing all the confusion in this question. This component doesn't own this data, some parent component does, all the manipulation of this data is being handled in the wrong place.

Comment: @Adam definitely!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Adam and @MichaelRovinsky , theres the result and my problems are fixed with the function slice, the component state should be update with a copy

```
let data = this.state.list.data;
        data.splice(row.id, 1);
        const copy = data.slice();
        this.setState({
            list: {
                ...this.state.list,
                data: copy,
            },
        });
```

Comment:  don't use splice. Working and done correctly are two different things.